# How do I add an entry to a json string?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a query

```
$rows = array();
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

resulting in

```
[{"id":"1","entry1":"value1"},{"id":"2","entry2":"value2"}]
```

I need to add a value to each result, resulting in

```
[{"id":"1","entry1":"value1","additionalentry":"additionalvalue"}{"id":"2","entry2":"value2","additionalentry":"additionalvalue"}]
```

How do I do this the correct way?

I've tried using something like this in and outside of the while loop:

```
$current_data = json_encode($r);
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true); 
$extra = array(  
    'additionalentry1'               =>     "additionalvalue1",  
    'additionalentry2'          =>     "additionalvalue2",  
    'additionalentry3'     =>     "additionalvalue3"  
);  
$array_data[] = $extra;
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);  
$rows[] = $final_data;
```

, but it breaks the json structure when I do it in the loop as it adds {'s and slashes,

and if I do it outside of the loop it just adds a third result instead of adding these values to the 2 results found.

```
[{"id":"1","entry1":"value1","additionalentry":"additionalvalue"},{"id":"2","entry2":"value2","additionalentry":"additionalvalue"},
{"additionalentry1":"additionalvalue1","additionalentry2":"additionalvalue2","additionalentry3":"additionalvalue3"}]
```

The only solution that did work but is not practical at all was to add

```
    $i++;
    $bs[] = json_encode($r);
```

in the while loop and then manipulate the strings and join them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to archive this. The simplest way, merge these arrays using `array_merge`

Here is example code

```
$extra = array(
    'additionalentry1'               =>     "additionalvalue1",
    'additionalentry2'          =>     "additionalvalue2",
    'additionalentry3'     =>     "additionalvalue3"
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $data[$key] = array_merge($value, $extra);
}

print_r($data);
```

I simply use `foreach` loop for `$data` and merge `$extra` array with existing array data of every `index` of `$data`

Implementation in your code, you can replace the following code with my above `loop` code

```
$array_data[] = $extra;
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);  
$rows[] = $final_data;
```